# WindowsBaloonTip / TrayTip Notifications with Alert box in python

Tags: python, notifications, pywin32, systray

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 machine.
My notifications are working fine. But when I included an alert box/dailog box, the process is ignoring the alert box code and the dialog box is not popping-up. 
My notification code is:

```
class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        iconPathName= "D:\icon.ico"

        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd) 
        print iconPathName
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
            hicon = LoadImage(hinst,iconPathName, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16,icon_flags)
        except:
            hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
            logging.debug("Image adding fail")
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "title")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        global sleep
        time.sleep(sleep)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, None)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0)
```

My alert box code is:

```
import win32api
a=0       
a=win32api.MessageBox(0, 'message', 'title',0)
```

First, I am using notification and then dialog box.
When I debug, the issue I found is due to `UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, hinst)`.
I tried with it and got an error reading as:

```
classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
pywintypes.error: (1410, 'RegisterClass', 'Class already exists.')
```

My requirement is to **call notification code from different functions and then dailog box from other function in a single process**.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a very similar problem: 
[Refresh Windows Balloon Tip from Python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091211/refresh-windows-balloon-tip-from-python-thread)

Check this:
[Multiple WindowsBaloonTip / TrayTip Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262941/multiple-windowsbaloontip-traytip-notifications?rq=1)

The above fix allowed me to nuke a window and unregister, but only from one thread. A separate thread cannot handle the same window. Not sure if that applies to functions as well..

*this is a comment, not an answer.. but I'm <50 for now.*